# Static resources not found in (Selenium) JUnit test for Play 2.0 application executed from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, junit, playframework, playframework-2.0

For my Play 2.0 application, I want to execute a (Selenium) JUnit test from Eclipse. 
The test case looks like:

```
@Test
public void runInBrowser() {
    running(testServer(47111, fakeApplication(...)), ChromeDriver.class,
        new Callback<TestBrowser>() {
            public void invoke(TestBrowser browser) {
                browser.goTo("http://localhost:47111");
                assertThat(...);
            }
    });
}
```

The test server starts but none of the static ressources (e.g., *.css, *.js, *.png) is available during the test, that is, accessing `http://localhost:47111` causes 404 for these resources.

My `routes` file contains:

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

The static resources are located in the folders: public\images ( *.png ), public\javascripts ( *.js ), public\stylesheets ( *.css ).

Outside the Eclipse test environment all static resources are found (e.g., executing the tests in the play console with "play test").

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution:

Replace

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="target/scala-2.10/classes_managed"/>
```

with

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="target/scala-2.10/classes"/>
```

in the Eclispe .classpath file.

Answer (score 0):

I found more information here [Assets missing during functional tests](http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/645-assets-missing-during-functional-tests)