# Play assets not served correctly when running WebDriver tests from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, assets, playframework-2.2

I've written some Selenium WebDriver tests running against my Play 2.2.2 app, and everything works fine if I run them with `play test` at the command line. However, if I run the tests from inside Eclipse, all the files served via the `Assets` controller return 404, although the main controller serves its pages correctly.

I'm using the provided test helper classes, `play.api.test.Helpers` and `FakeApplication`. Setting the `path` hasn't helped:

```
new FakeApplication(path = new File("/path/to/play/app"))
```

Comment: This appears to do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20249599/61298

Comment: Possible duplicate of [assets are not loaded in functional test mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791992/assets-are-not-loaded-in-functional-test-mode)