# How to run functional Play tests in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, playframework-2.3

Tests like the following run as expected when run with `activator test`. When run from Eclipse, the Play application appears to start normally, but requests to localhost:9000 from within the `run` method all result in a 404. What am I missing?

```
public void test() {
  running(testServer(9000), new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    ...
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25051844/1144085. The problem is that the generated `.classpath` is missing the directory containing the assets; this can be fixed by adding the following line to the `build.sbt`:

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )
```

Beware that the directory can be empty (or outdated) if `sbt web-test:assets` hasn't run, see https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3234.